# Plant ID2 ground cover w/ small white cup flowers

Tags: identification

I'm back with another of my dog-walk inspired questions. This plant appears *everywhere* on my walks with my dog. It's a low-lying ground cover with viney stems and small white cup-like flowers. It would be perfect for a narrow area between my house and a brick walk way, but I don't know if it's a perennial or an annual. (I suspect it's a self-seeding annual, based on where it comes up.) I'm sure it's considered a weed where I see it (along curbs and in thinly mulched flowerbeds), but I like it and would consider it suitable for the purpose of filling in a six-inch area between the house and the walk (just there to allow drainage from the walk).

[image: groundcover w white flowers]

Comment: what part of the world are you located in?

Comment: OH! Sorry, I should have said. I'm in S.E. Michigan. These plants appear to be volunteers rather than intentionally planted. The task of identifying them is made harder by the fact that they're mixed in with some other sort of ground cover. If you enlarge the picture, you can see that the flowers come from some sort of viney plant, but they're mixed in with some sort of fleshy-stemmed plant.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like bindweed, probably *Convolvulus arvensis*. Very common invasive species in MI, officially designated as ["noxious weed"](https://www.michigan.gov/documents/mdard/Michigan_Prohibited_and_Restricted_Weeds_641413_7.pdf).  It seems to be very hard to get rid off once established.

I too am rather fond of it, it is a common native wildflower where I grew up, but, no, I would not recommend introducing this into your garden in the US.